# Select distinct query taking too long in databricks

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I ran this SQL query in databricks to check the distinct values of a column in a parquet file:

```
SELECT distinct country
FROM parquet_table
```

This took 1.31 hours to run. Am I doing something wrong here that such a simple query is taking so long?

Comment: try, spark.table("parquet_table").select('country).dropDuplicates()

Comment: Distinct is more performance intensive than Group By. You should try converting the query to corresponding group by e.g. select col1,col2 from parquet_table group by col1,col2. Other factors that can affect query performance include table size and cluster size. Please share some details on these aspects as well.

Comment: I just did a select count(*) and it returned 5,577,950,744. The cluster size is 1.86TB.